# React: Firebase Listener Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm following this screencast on YouTube, but for the life of me I can't seem to get my database to talk to my React app.

The `componentDidMount()` function is being run, but the `.on()` listener function isn't firing, it seems.

My code looks like this:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

var config = {
  // config from firebase db lives here
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      speed: 10
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('react');
    const speedRef = rootRef.child('speed');

    speedRef.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({
        speed: snap.val()
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{this.state.speed}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

FWIW, my db looks like this:

[image]

I'm getting zero errors in the console, and completely out of ideas. Anything I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solved! It had to do with my Firebase READ rules. Can someone close this.

Comment: the proper thing to do is make an answer to your question and then accept that answer. This was my problem too, and your question/answer got me to the correct answer as well.

Comment: @awwester Added answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! This issue had to do with my Firebase READ rules. Check the rules on your database if you run into a similar issue.